# What’s the difference between mv-ing a file vs just writing to the same filename

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I’m working on some ffmpeg+nginx projects and there is a behavior that almost makes sense but I still just don’t get it.

ffmpeg is using a file, `overlay.png` to watermark a video stream.

When I write a new image to that location, ffmpeg doesn’t see the changed image and my stream watermark stays the same.

When I write the new image to `overlay2.png` and then `mv overlay2.png overlay.png`, ffmpeg sees the new image and updates almost instantly.

**What is the difference between writing a new image to an existing file versus moving an image to an existing name.**

### Ran via nginx exec, works correctly

- Stream from OBS to nginx
- nginx passes RTMP to ffmpeg
- ffmpeg centers `overlay.png` on top of the video
- ffmpeg scales the overlay to be the same resolution as the video(no aspect ratio math yet)
- ffmpeg correctly updates the image only if the image is update with `mv`

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/$name
  -f image2 -loop 1 -re -i /opt/images/overlayimage.png
  -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,split=1[overlayimage]"
  -map '[overlayimage]' -map 0:a -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -f flv -g 30 -preset veryfast rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_wm
  -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -f flv -g 30 -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name;
```

#### Generate image in a loop and update for RTMP

```
while true
 do
     convert -background transparent -fill red  -font Nimbus-Sans-L-Bold -size 1024x768 -gravity center label:"$(date)" temp.png 
     sleep 1 && mv -f temp.png overlayimage.png  
     convert -background transparent -fill blue  -font Nimbus-Sans-L-Bold -size 1024x768 -gravity center label:"$(date)" temp.png 
     sleep 1 && mv -f temp.png overlayimage.png
     convert -background transparent -fill green  -font Nimbus-Sans-L-Bold -size 1024x768 -gravity center label:"$(date)" temp.png 
     sleep 1 && mv -f temp.png overlayimage.png
     convert -background transparent -fill purple  -font Nimbus-Sans-L-Bold -size 1024x768 -gravity center label:"$(date)" temp.png 
     sleep 1 && mv -f temp.png overlayimage.png
 done
```

### PROBLEM/QUESTION

If I use `convert .... overlayimage.png`, `ffmpeg` won't see the changed image.  When I use the intermediate file and `mv overlayimage2.png overlayimage.png` it works fine.

I'm just curious why `mv` is better than an in-place update.

---

To help people who Google “ffmpeg image not updating” or "ffmpeg overlay image centered and scaled over live stream".

Comment: Please update your post with the ffmpeg command, i.e. specifically how ffmpeg was told to read overlay.png in the first place. There are several answers in general, but not all of them may apply to ffmpeg specifically.

Comment: @user1686 I've updated the question.  Thanks for jumping in!

Answer (score 1):

The update of the input has to be atomic. Basically, the file should not be 0-sized or blocked or missing when ffmpeg reads it. If it is, ffmpeg image reader aborts with EOF. `mv` is much faster and usually succeeds.